# Matlab and Java 8

Tags: java, matlab, matlab-compiler

I'm going to develop a complex Java application which should run on a machine with Debian 8.6 and JRE 8u71 installed. Furthermore, the application makes use of some Java classes, developed and compiled in Matlab.

By now, Matlab (Version R2015b - R2017a) supports Java version 7u61.
So I would like to know if anyone has some experience with using Matlab and a JDK 8 installation. I know about following article:

http://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/130359-how-do-i-change-the-java-virtual-machine-jvm-that-matlab-is-using-on-windows

but I'm not sure if this is quite a good idea. Furthermore, will this change the Java version of the Matlab Compiler Runtime as well? 
For testing it is also necessary for me to integrate some Java classes (version 8u71) in Matlab.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using Matlab 2015b with Java 8 on both Windows and Linux for a while now (through setting `MATLAB_JAVA` environmental variable), and never experienced any issues (unlike when I tried using some older Matlab versions with Java 7). This lets you use java classes compiled with Java 8, i.e. all the fancy language features like lambdas etc.

Comment: So you changed the JVM Matlab uses to Java 8?

Comment: OK, great. So I'll give it a try.

Comment: have you tried to use the Matlab Compiler SDK for building Java packages? This crashes on my machine right after startup....

Comment: No, I haven't tried using Matlab Compiler with java 8, so it might indeed not work..

Comment: I've also been using Java 8 with the latest Matlab version (2016+) so that I can access JavaFX and it has worked well.